# Show two columns from SQLite as same string in a listview in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-manifest

Hi I am developing an android in which I am loading data from database and showing it in a List View.
My code is as follows

```
public class rel extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.refill);
    //Creating an object called mydbhelper
    Dbms mydbhelper = new Dbms(this);
    //Loading the database in writable format
    SQLiteDatabase db=mydbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] id= new String[]{"_id","medicine","hs"};
    //Cursor
    Cursor c = db.query("medicines",id,null,null,null, null,null);
    startManagingCursor(c);
    String[] from = new String[]{"medicine"};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textlist1};
     // Now creating an array adapter and set it to display using my row
    SimpleCursorAdapter notes =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);



}
```

What i want to achieve is show a list view as "Medicine-hs" in which medicine is from one column and hs is from an another column of database. For example as 
XYZ-HS1
ABC-HS2
as the listview contents

How to achieve this?
Right now I am able to get only Medicine

Please give your kind suggestions

}

Comment: That gives an error as such a field does not exist in the database.Better read the question clearly and understand how things work internally before trying to show your smartness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to say replace this:

```
    String[] from = new String[]{"medicine"};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textlist1};
```

with this:

```
    String[] from = new String[]{"medicine", "medicine-hs"};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.textlist1, R.id.textlist2};
```

You will of course need to have a R.id.textlist2 available to use in your layout.

EDIT: Reverted back to the previous revision, which solved the problem.

Comment: If you need further clarification let me know.

Comment: Hi, here medicine and hs are from different columns of a database. How can I get them into one single String? Regards ChinniKrishna kothapalli

Comment: Hi jack figured it out. Thanks for your help. Just need to add another text box as you have told and need to redefine the XML layout a bit to get it. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is execute the `rawQuery()` method off the DBHelper class with SQL that combines the fields like so:

```
SELECT medicine + "-" + hs AS medicineHs FROM medicines ...
```

so the string array would be

```
String[] from = new String[]{"medicineHs"};
```

Comment: Wow an elegant solution but it lacks selecting the '_id' column which gives an error. Actually I am new to SQL so maybe facing problems :-)

Comment: Oh right. So the select would be: SELECT _id, medicine + "-" + hs AS medicineHs FROM medicines ...